# node js api in hyperledger fabric

Tags: api, hyperledger-fabric

2022-09-14T07:37:21.040Z - error: [DiscoveryResultsProcessor]: parseDiscoveryResults[User] - Channel:mychannel received discovery error:failed constructing descriptor for chaincodes:<name:"User" >
Failed to submit transaction: Error: DiscoveryService: User error: failed constructing descriptor for chaincodes:<name:"User" >

when I hit API from post man i receive this error

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes when the chaincode name given is wrong. Make sure the chaincode('User' in this case) is committed to channel mychannel before sending transactions using SDK.